# Why do counits go that way?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, education, adjoint-functors

Imagine you want to motivate for an audience the definition of an adjunction in terms of unit and counit. So you can say: Often two functors
$\mathcal{C} \begin{array}{c} \stackrel{\large F}{\rightarrow} \\ \stackrel{\leftarrow}{G}\end{array} \mathcal{D}$ are not really inverse, up to isomorphism, but still, the compositions $F \circ G$ and $G \circ F$ are somehow "connected" to the identity functors. So we have natural transformations
$$\eta : \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{C}} \to G \circ F,$$
$$\varepsilon : F \circ G \to \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{D}},$$
which should be compatible in a suitable way. Then someone says:

"Wait, why not taking $\varepsilon : \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{D}} \to F \circ G$ instead? What's wrong with that?"

What would you answer?

Just to be clear: I understand the concept of an adjunction and know that $\varepsilon$ has to go from $F \circ G$ to $\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{D}}$, but I am not sure how to explain this  to a novice without going into the details of the notion of an adjunction, for example the triangle identities or the alternative hom-set-definition, which by the way I would like to exclude from the discussion here. A good answer should be intuitive.

Notice that it is not true that we cannot state any compatibility conditions between two natural transformations $\eta : \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{C}} \to G \circ F$ and $\varepsilon : \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{D}} \to F \circ G$. An obvious candidate would be
$$F \circ \eta = \varepsilon \circ  F : F \to F \circ G \circ F$$
and/or
$$\eta \circ  G = G \circ  \varepsilon : G \to G \circ F \circ G.$$
By the way, does this concept have a name?

Comment: I think the easiest answer is that it would break self-duality.

Comment: Somehow my question is not taken too serious by the "answers". I know how to motivate adjunctions via examples, hom-sets etc., but that's not the point. The first line of my question is:  "Imagine you want to motivate for an audience the definition of an adjunction in terms of unit and counit."

Comment: Well, it's a bit of a circus act to try to say _anything_ meaningful about an adjunction in unit-counit terms if you're not allowed to refer to the triangle equations. There's no _a priori_ guarantee that it's really possible to say anything meaningful about an incomplete definition. It's a bit like asking, when presenting the definition of a group, why we're using a binary operation rather than a ternary one, without being allowed to talk about associativity or inverses. The real answer might just be "wait and see what I'm going to do with this".

Comment: Also, note that the dual of the notion you're considering -- where you have $\eta: GF \to 1$ and $\epsilon : FG \to 1$ with your compatibility conditions -- does have a name. It's called a _Morita context_. I've only ever seen it used in Morita theory in a context where what we're really interested in is getting an equivalence.

Comment: @tcamps (first comment): Yes I know that, but my question is about teaching. As I've said, imagine you are faced with the question "Why not $\varepsilon : \mathrm{id} \to F \circ G$?". One possible answer would be "Just wait what we will do with it.", but I doubt that this is the best one.

Comment: @tcamps (second comment): Thank you, I didn't know this general notion! Any Morita context restricts to an equivalence of categories ("Morita equivalence"), by looking at the fixed points. This is quite similar to adjunctions.

Comment: @Martin: I haven't checked this, but with the counit going the other way I don't see any reason to expect uniqueness, which is a very important property of adjoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this veers too close to talking about the triangle equations, but I find it suggestive that it's *possible* to paste the unit and the counit in *some* way when the counit goes the right way around, whereas if it goes the wrong way around, there's simply no pasting that you can possibly do. With no pasting, there wouldn't be anything you could "do" with the data of an adjunction, except maybe to have it interact with other adjunctions.

Maybe you could make something of the following fact: if a functor is a self-adjoint endofunctor, and you have the counit the wrong way around, then the unit and counit have the same domain and codomain. Maybe that seems a little weird.

Otherwise -- examples?

**EDIT**
From the way the question is worded, it sounds like you want to motivate the adjunction concept as a weakening of the equivalence concept. Perhaps the question "why doesn't $\epsilon$ go the other way?" comes from the fact that when we're talking about equivalences, it often *is* presented as going the other way. Then it will make sense to point out that in the equivalence case, since the 2-cells are invertible, there really are 2-cells going in *both* directions, and so we're free to generalize it by choosing whatever direction we please. Then you can motivate the actual choice of directions by saying "wait and see the cool equations that this allows me to impose".

Comment: "there's simply no pasting that you can possibly do" is not correct, see my edit.

Comment: I'm on a roll today!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: There's no contradiction between your edit and tcamps's answer: you wrote a possible compatibility condition, tcamps stated there's no interesting pastings. And I think pasting is exactly what makes adjunction formally interesting, and makes $η$ and $ε$ into a relaxed kind of inverses of each other (and not, as in what you suggested, a relaxed kind of the same thing).

Comment: Actually there are pastings; whether they're interesting seems subjective. For example, we can take ϵ∘GηF.

Comment: You mean $FηG ∘ ε$ I assume? Yeah, there's that. There's even interesting equations you could write down: $FηG ∘ ε = ε * ε (= FGε ∘ ε = εFG ∘ ε)$  and a similar one for $GεF ∘ η$. Still, doesn't come close to the real adjunction, where unit and counit are a) dual, b) somewhat inverse. edit: And besides, these are of course implied by Martin's simple equations.

Comment: @tcamps: I've just seen your edit. Thank you for that. In fact, I would like to motivate adjunctions as you have described. Equivalences are usually written down as functors $F,G$ with $FG \cong \mathrm{id}$ and $GF \cong \mathrm{id}$, so yeah, here we have to do something to get the correct direction. Since you mentioned Morita contexts, it is now apparent that both directions make sense, right? But again, I would like to know if there is anything we can say *a priori* about our choice.

Answer (score 1):

The unit-counit definition of an adjunction makes sense in any 2-category, and so it makes sense in any monoidal category, where it recovers the definition of a dualizable object. So you can motivate this somewhat more general notion using the familiar special case of vector spaces: when a vector space $V$ has a dual $V^{\ast}$, there is a unit map $1 \to V^{\ast} \otimes V$, namely the coevaluation, and also a counit map $V \otimes V^{\ast} \to 1$, namely the evaluation.

Of course it's hard to distinguish between the two possible orders of the tensor product here since $\otimes$ is symmetric monoidal. At this point I would draw the triangle identities using string diagrams, which justifies using the orderings above, although if you're going to both avoid that and also the homset definition of an adjunction I don't know what to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

tcamps gave what I think is the correct answer (nice pasting diagrams justify the choice formally, examples justify it's usefulness), but here's an alternate approach which might have some pedagogical merit, if you don't think it's too roundabout.

1. Use the adjunction isomorphism as the definition, or state that it's equivalent to the (unit, counit) one you are presenting. The latter is better because it generalizes, but the adjunction isomorphism I think is easier to motivate, because there's couple of really obvious examples (familiar examples of free algebras, e.g. free modules, and familiar examples of monoidal closure, e.g. Set).
2. Only thing you know for sure a general category has are identities. The two most obvious things you get using identities and the adjunction isomorphism go in different directions.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, as tcamp also commented, there also exists a similar construction as adjunctions in any bicategory where the 'unit' and 'counit' go in the same direction, and these are the (dual) **Morita contexts**, and it is also worth to study, having already wide literature, at least in its origin world of rings. 
(Note that adjoint *equivalences* are immediately Morita [and dual Morita] contexts by flipping the [co-]unit.)

Secondly, consider the two (pseudo) embeddings of bicategories ${\bf Cat}\to{\bf Prof}$ sending $F\mapsto F_*$ and $F\mapsto F^*$, where $F_*=(a,b)\mapsto\hom_B(Fa,b)$ and $F^*=(b,a)\mapsto\hom_B(b,Fa)$ for a functor $F:A\to B$.
Observe that both of these are *contravariant* in exactly one dimension ($F\mapsto F^*$ on arrows and $F\mapsto F_*$ on 2-cells).

Moreover, we can roll these two maps in one embedding of double categories ${\bf Q}({\bf Cat})\to{\bf Q}({\bf Prof})$ which is contravariant in exactly one direction, where ${\bf Q}(B)$ means the double category of Ehresmann quintets of the bicategory $B$. 
Consequently, orthogonal *adjoint* pairs in ${\bf Q}({\bf Cat})\ $ (i.e. adjoint functors with counit-unit-definition) correspond to *companion* pairs in ${\bf Q}({\bf Prof})\ $ (which yields the "$L_*\simeq R^*$" definition).

Comment: Thank you, but of course it is not wise to talk about profunctors and bicategories when one just wants to motivate the notion of an adjunction directly.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure one can give a justification from scratch. However, an important algebraic motivation of adjunction is to formalize the "free construction" on a set in a given algebraic theory. Leaning on the basic free constructions (groups, abelian groups, modules, rings, etc.) that your student should know, you have a panel of adjunctions $F \dashv U$ to show off, where $U$ is some kind of "underlying set" functor.

Now, the counit can only go in the direction $FU \to \mathrm{id}$ : $FU(x)$ is the algebraic object of "formal combinations" of elements of $x$ ; one can certainly transform a formal combination into a concrete computation, but the other way around would be highly non canonical.