# Why do the unit and counit of an adjunction work in opposite directions?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

This is probably a very basic question, because it seems to me that this is literally the point of an adjunction, but I don't really get it still. (note, I don't really get adjunctions in general).

if $F:D\to C$ is left adjoint to $G$ then there are two natural transformations

$\eta:FG\to 1_C$

$\gamma:1_D\to GF$

Why is it not $\gamma:GF\to 1_D$? It seems weird to me that the counit and unit would have opposite types, and I'm not sure why they would? I feel like not understanding this is the thing that's preventing me from understanding adjunctions.

Comment: What's your go-to example of adjunction ? If you don't have one, you should probably get one (actually, the more, the better). Mine is the free/forgetful adjunction between groups and sets. In that case, it's clear that there can't be a natural map in the direction you suggest; this example always helps me remember the directions of things, and the identities etc.

Comment: Notationally, the counit is almost always written with $\varepsilon$ or $\epsilon$ and the unit with $\eta$. You have the counit written with $\eta$ and the unit written with $\gamma$. Why would it be natural for them to have "similar" types? Also, why not have $\eta:1_C\to FG$ rather than changing $\gamma$? At any rate, I find the $\mathsf{Hom}(F-,=)\cong\mathsf{Hom}(-,G=)$ definition much more intuitive and enlightening and practically useful for computation. (This is not to say one shouldn't be familiar with all the formulations of adjunction.)

Comment: Maybe a way to understand this is the case where you have an adjoint equivalence, is both the unit and the counit are isomorphisms. In this case, there is also an adjunction the other way, where $G$ is left adjoint to $F$. If you think about it, you want the new unit to be the inverse of the old counit, and the new counit to be the inverse of the unit. I think this fact is more intuitive. But the only way for it to work is to have the opposite types

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do counits go that way?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235211/why-do-counits-go-that-way)

Answer (score 2):

It's because the unit $\eta$ comes from transposing the identity $Fx\to Fx$ across the adjunction to get a map $x\to GFx$ and the counit $\varepsilon$ comes from transposing the identity $Gy\to Gy$ to get a map $FGy\to y$. There's no way to use the adjunction to produce maps with the signatures you're wondering about: in an adjunction, you can turn an $F$ into a $G$ by moving it from left to right, and you can turn a $G$ into an $F$ by moving it from right to left, but the other two possibilities are not valid.